# Animate doesn't animate with LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, animate

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{animate}
\listfiles
\begin{document}
\animategraphics[palindrome,autoplay,width=\textwidth,controls]{5}{Testsaves}{0}{1}
\end{document}
```

It needs two images (Testsaves0 and Testsaves1) in the same folder.
If I compile it with pdflatex, everything works and it is animated in Adobe Acrobat when I open it. The buttons work, too.

If I compile the same code with LuaLaTeX, it includes only the first image in the pdf, and nothing happens.

From the log files:

pdflatex:

```
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
)) <./Testsaves0.png> <./Testsaves1.png>
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `BeforeClearDocument' on input line 6.
```

LuaLaTeX:

```
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
))<./Testsaves0.png>
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `BeforeClearDocument' on input line 6.
```

System is a Windows 7 PC with TeXLive 2014 completely updated to today. I think it worked before, but I'm not 100% sure. I tried rolling the animate package back to my earliest backed up revision (35387) but that didn't change anything.

File List:

```
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 animate.sty    2014/12/04 PDF animations from files and inline graphics
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 ifdraft.sty    2008/08/11 v1.3 Detect class options draft and final (HO)
    calc.sty    2014/10/28 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
atenddvi.sty    2007/04/17 v1.1 At end DVI hook (HO)
zref-abspage.sty    2012/04/04 v2.24 Module abspage for zref (HO)
zref-base.sty    2012/04/04 v2.24 Module base for zref (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
luatex-loader.sty    2010/03/09 v0.4 Lua module loader (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
zref-lastpage.sty    2012/04/04 v2.24 Module lastpage for zref (HO)
atveryend.sty    2011/06/30 v1.8 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
  animfp.sty    2009/07/23 fixed point addition for animate.sty
graphics.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0p Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
 ***********
```

Comment: Did you send the bug report? If yes, can you give the link to it? I still get the same error.

Comment: I reported the bug: https://github.com/ho-tex/oberdiek/issues/34

Answer (score 5, accepted):

animate tests the graphics for identity to avoid to include the same file twice. This test fails for lualatex: The luatex implementation in `pdftexcmds` of `\pdf@filemdfivesum` seems to be faulty. I get the same values for the two graphics with lualatex but different values when I compile with pdflatex.

You can get around the problem by forcing animate to check only the file names. But I suggest to send Heiko Oberdiek a bug report.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{animate}
\makeatletter\def\@anim@pdfmdfivesum#1{#1}\makeatother

\begin{document}
\makeatletter 
\pdf@filemdfivesum{gans1.png}  

\pdf@filemdfivesum{gans2.png}
\makeatother

\animategraphics[palindrome,autoplay,width=\textwidth,controls]{5}{gans}{1}{2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I will send a bug report. Thanks for the workaround, it works great!

Comment: The problem seems that it only compares until it encounters a NULL byte.

Comment: This problem is Windows-only. I could verify this using a set of PNGs of mine. On Linux, the md5 sums are correctly calculated.

Comment: **January 2018:** The problem still occurs - I used the proposed solution from Ulrike and it works.

Comment: Really!? This should be reported to the author of `pdftexcmds` package. Different file checksum computation by pdftex and Luatex is a major bug.

Comment: @AlexG Done: https://github.com/ho-tex/oberdiek/issues/34

Comment: @manuel Already seen it and added a test file. Could you tell me what you get if you run `lualatex` on it?

Comment: @manuel Oh, David Carlisle has already replied.

Answer (score 5):

`animate` uses `\pdf@filemdfivesum` from the `pdftexcmds` package to avoid multiple inclusion of the same file. It calculates the MD5 check sum of files to be embedded.

The reported error occurs on Windows only.

The reason is that Windows distinguishes between opening files in text and binary mode. The C `fopen()` is mapped to Lua `io.open()` and uses the same argument list. The flag `b` (binary mode) should be added to the `io.open()` call to ensure correct reading of files on all platforms.

This patch fixes the problem:

```
--- texmf-dist/scripts/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.lua.orig
+++ texmf-dist/scripts/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.lua
@@ -250,7 +250,7 @@
       if not offset then
         offset = 0
       end
-      local filehandle = io.open(foundfile, "r")
+      local filehandle = io.open(foundfile, "rb")
       if filehandle then
         if offset > 0 then
           filehandle:seek("set", offset)
@@ -270,7 +270,7 @@
 function filemdfivesum(filename)
   local foundfile = kpse.find_file(filename, "tex", true)
   if foundfile then
-    local filehandle = io.open(foundfile, "r")
+    local filehandle = io.open(foundfile, "rb")
     if filehandle then
       local contents = filehandle:read("*a")
       escapehex(md5.sum(contents))
```

Comment: **January 2018:**  The problem still occurs - I used Ulrikes answer and it works.

Comment: Ok, Ulrike's solution replaces file content checksum comparison by simple file name comparison. This doesn't prevent double inclusion if another file with different file name is actually a copy of a previously included file.

Comment: Thanks for replying. At the moment this is not a üproblem for me. I did not understand what I have to do with your answer and Ulrike's answer seemed easy to "implement". Maybe your solution will get "official" in the future since LuaLaTeX is getting more and more famous (I assume).

Comment: this is fixed in github but ctan upload seems to be failing this evening, but expect it to appear there soon

Comment: This is now installed at ctan